# Can't focus from main window after closing dialog from other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc

I create a new `CWindThread` in `CWinApp::InitInstance()`. In that thread, I create a dialog (for displaying a progress bar in that dialog).

After finishing `InitInstance()`, I close the dialog by calling `DestroyWindow()` from the dialog, but the application is loosing focus from main window.

I used `AfxGetMainWnd()->SetActiveWindow();` to set focus for main window but it is not working.

How can I return the focus to the main window after closing the dialog?

Comment: Have you tried SetFocus()-function ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646312(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I used `pMainFrame->SetFocus()` but it doesn't work

Comment: Your implementation is backwards: Offload the work to a worker thread, and notify your GUI thread from there. Cross-thread window hierarchies are very difficult to maintain.

Comment: My temporary solution is to try closing the dialog before main thread call to open main window(main frame). It worked but I think it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real good way to do that. The focus is set per thread. So there is no "focus" over all windows.

The only chance you have is to set the new foreground window, that belongs to the other thread with [SetForegorundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). From within the same application this should work without restrictions.

If it doesn't work you need to "synch" both message queues. This is done by [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956(v=vs.85).aspx). If both messages queue are already attached, than there is no problem with settings the focus directly. But the behaviour of the application will change... Please read the docs, of the functions I linked too.

Comment: The problem is complicated, because some states of the system are always per thread and not system wide. Focus is such a thing, like the active window and others. Just give SetForegroundWIndow a chance instead SetFocus... that is may be the fast solution.

Comment: `AttachThreadInput` is a no-op in this scenario. Once you install a cross-thread parent/owner relationship, the system implicitly attaches the input queues of the participating threads.

Comment: This is only complicated because your solution is wrong

Answer (score 0):

When a modal popup window is displayed, the reason a user cannot interact with the owner window is that it is disabled. When the modal window is destroyed, care must be taken to re-enable the owner window BEFORE destroying the popup as windows cannot activate a disabled window. This is the usual cause of popup windows re-activating the wrong window.

Comment: Modality is implemented using owner/owned relationships, not child/parent relationships.